# setFilterFunction of sap.m.Input in not triggering when input is used as a template in table?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to use setFilterFunction method of sap.m.Input. I am using the input as template of sap.ui.table.Table ,but this method is not triggering but if i use input box independently its getting triggered.So please help me how to call the method.

Comment: Could you please share the relevant bits of your code?

Comment: this is the exapmle i have written                   http://jsbin.com/desiwojeti/edit?html,output

Comment: but if i write only input box this function is getting trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define `oSource` variable, which will give event source.

Check out the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zibul/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: thanks for correction but i want filter function to work. i want once if we select the suggested value and again if i type the charcter than it should again show the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't see an easy way to get your filter function called by `sap.ui.table`.

I personally found it the easiest for `sap.ui.table` to just enrich my data model with a new property that suits my filtering needs and use this newly created property as the `filterProperty` of the table.